# How To Run XCTest in Xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xcode5, xctest

I'm trying the XCTest framework

```
@implementation UnitTestPOCTests

- (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];
    // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
}

- (void)tearDown
{
    // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
    [super tearDown];
}

- (void)testAditionClass
{
    Addition *addObj = [[Addition alloc]init];
    XCTAssertNotNil(addObj,@"AddtionClassExists");
}
```

I wrote the testAditionClass test method inside my test class, but when i run the test methods its showing Testing.... in the status bar

[image]

its not even getting terminated.

If any one know the the solution please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint to the test method to check if it's being run?

Comment: @Fogmeister I added a brake point to that method but its not even getting called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem by opening the simulator you will have the following options in menu

[image]

if you tap on reset content and setting.

Then try running unit test it works for me.